# Multiple instances of java web app share the same route

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

Suppose I have a java web app which has a endpoint `/hello`, I want to start multi instance of the web app at the same time which can be achieved by using different listening port on each instance.

But what I want is that all instances can share same route, i.e. when I make a request to `http://lcoalhost/hello`, it will automatically (load balance)route to one of multi instances. Why I want this is that when deploying micro service by k8s, we can have many pods for one application and these pods share single service(i.e single delicated url)

In java, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to run a load balancer in front of your instances (e.g. traefik)

Comment: Each pod has its own ip number.

Answer (score 0):

You would not use different listening ports, each pod has a dedicated IP address (Pod IP) and therefore the container can use whatever port is desired.

The kubernetes concept of a *Service* aggregates all Pods (using labels as criteria) and load balances tcp connections across all pods.

In order to access the service externally you can use an *Ingress* or *LoadBalancer*.

Comment: If we want to try it locally, it seems spring cloud load balance is one solution

Comment: I would not use a different architekture for local testing. You can use a simple docker-compose setup with a reverse proxy to approximate the kubernetes environment